# Удаление нескольких записей из таблицы по id

Tags: php, mysql

Как сделать нормальный код из этого бреда?

Смысл такой, на одной странице пользователь ставит галочки на сообщения, которые ему нужно удалить.

```
  $mass = ( $_POST['sold'] );

   mysql_query("DELETE FROM massage WHERE id = $mass[0]");
   mysql_query("DELETE FROM massage WHERE id = $mass[1]");
   mysql_query("DELETE FROM massage WHERE id = $mass[2]");
   mysql_query("DELETE FROM massage WHERE id = $mass[3]");
   mysql_query("DELETE FROM massage WHERE id = $mass[4]");
   mysql_query("DELETE FROM massage WHERE id = $mass[5]");
   mysql_query("DELETE FROM massage WHERE id = $mass[6]");
```

и так далее...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так

```
mysql_query('DELETE FROM message WHERE id IN ( ' . join( ',', $mass ) . ' );');
```

Лучше так

```
mysql_query(
  'DELETE FROM message'.
  'WHERE id IN ( '.join( ',', $mass ).' ) AND user_id = '.$user_id.';'
);
```

Ещё лучше сделать приведение типов к INT для элементов `$mass`

Comment: именно это я и имел введу кагбы ...

Comment: А о том, что данные от пользователя желательно заэскейпить, все дружно забыли:)

Comment: @KoVadim, Читайте внимательно:
>>> Ещё лучше сделать приведение типов к INT для элементов $mass

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM massage WHERE id IN ($mass[0], $mass[1], $mass[2], $mass[3], $mass[4] ...);
```